Как принимать айди всех сгруппированных фото в телеграме?
Пишу бота, сохраняющего заметки пользователя. Возникла проблема с добавлением возможности принимания прикреплённых сгруппированных фото (файлы, видео и т.п.). Как я могу за одно принятие сообщения получить айди всех фото. Я знаю про media_group_id, но как из этого получить айди фоток не знаю :(
Пишу на пайтоне, библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1572023/562052
